# How to retrieve member size of google contact group.?

Tags: google-contacts-api

I want to retrieve member size of Contact Group. I am using below URL.

```
String pageUrl="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/" +
                "?xoauth_requestor_id="+userEmail+"&group="+groupId;
```

It is retrieving by default 25 records.Though there are more than 25 records. how can i retrieve size of contact group..? Which url i need to use.?

Answer (score 0):

```
 pageUrl += "&max-results=10000"
```